# Type imitation in python

Tags: python, haskell

What is the best way to imitate types in Python?

How this `TestResult` Haskell datatype could be defined in Python?

```
data TestResult
  = TestResult {name :: String,
                feature :: String,
                passed :: Bool,
                errorMessage :: String}
```

I tried that, but it looks kinda silly. Are there another ways to approach that behavior?

```
class TestResult:
    def __init__(self, name, feature, passed, errorMessage):
        self.name         = name
        self.feature      = feature
        self.passed       = passed
        self.errorMessage = errorMessage
```

I'm not looking for some type-superfluity, but for something like "type constructor" magic kludge to combine some data stubs in a logically single thing.

Comment: Привет, дорогой Дима Маликов.
Если ты еще не знаешь, то меня зовут Игнат!
Из наших деревенских ребят я твой самый большой фанат
Я живу в деревне, которая называется Большие Валенки.
Я люблю твои песни с тех самых пор, когда еще сам был маленьким...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For immutable data you can use `collections.namedtuple`:

```py
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> TestResult = namedtuple("TestResult", "name feature passed errorMessage")
>>> TestResult("a", "b", True, "c")
TestResult(name='a', feature='b', passed=True, errorMessage='c')
```

Comment: @ДМИТРИЙМАЛИКОВ: I don't see how this is "better" – it's equivalent, and you are free to prefer it.  You can access the fields with dot notation `x.name`, `x.feature` etc.  If you want a `dict`-like notation, how about `dict(name="a", feature="b", ...)`?

Answer (score 2):

You code looks good to me. You can look into [NamedTuple](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple)s if you want a less verbose version.